# How do I restart airflow webserver?

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

I am using airflow for my data pipeline project. I have configured my project in airflow and start the airflow server as a backend process using following command

```
airflow webserver -p 8080 -D True
```

Server running successfully in backend. Now I want to enable authentication in airflow and done configuration changes in airflow.cfg, but authentication functionality is not reflected in server. when I stop and start airflow server in my local machine it works.
So How can I restart my daemon airflow webserver process in my server??

Comment: airflow webserver -p 8080 -D

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I advice running airflow in a robust way, with auto-recovery with systemd
so you can do:
 - to start `systemctl start airflow`
 - to stop `systemctl stop airflow`
 - to restart `systemctl restart airflow`
For this you'll need a systemd 'unit' file.
As a (working) example you can use the following:
`put it in /lib/systemd/system/airflow.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
[Service]
PIDFile=/run/airflow/webserver.pid
EnvironmentFile=/home/airflow/airflow.env
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'export AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/airflow ; airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid'
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s
PrivateTmp=true
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

P.S: change AIRFLOW_HOME to where your airflow folder with the config

Comment: This is the right way to do it. There's example scripts for both upstart and systemd: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/scripts

Comment: This is also discussed in the airflow docs here : http://pythonhosted.org/airflow/configuration.html#integration-with-systemd

Comment: If you are familiar with daemon-izing airflow, can you and/or @7yl4r please help me? I'm having trouble with daemonizing it from within a virtualenv. Thanks!

Comment: I got this error when i tried your solution "Job for airflow.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status airflow.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details"

Comment: Just a question here, suppose we have apache-airflow in a virtual environment, would you have to activate environment or is there a way to execute the airflow webserver command with the file present in the bin folder of our virtual environment

Comment: @AmartyaGaur virtual-env is just a folder so yes, you can execute anything in it directly.
"Activating" a virtual-env is simply aliasing the 'python' commands for the given shell (where the virtual-env is activated) so that any time you call 'python' or 'pip' or 'airflow' it's redirected to the bin folder of your virtual-env. To prevent confusion I think it's better to make sure you 'activate' the virtual-env that you are currently working on. On production servers, you usually don't work with virtual-envs.

Answer (score 52):

Can you check `$AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow-webserver.pid` for the process id of your webserver daemon?

Then pass it a kill signal to kill it

```
cat $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow-webserver.pid | xargs kill -9
```

Then clear the pid file

```
cat /dev/null >  $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow-webserver.pid
```

Then just run

```
airflow webserver -p 8080 -D True
```

to restart the daemon.

Comment: Why do you need `True` after -D ?

Comment: You're right. As long as you pass the flag you don't need to explicitly pass `True`

Comment: This does not seem to work with me. I can still see the pid when i use `cat`
I am using WSL 2 btw

Comment: @captaincapsaicin: I have approed an edit of this answer. Please go over it to make sure it corresponds to what you intended.

Answer (score 28):

This worked for me (multiple times! :D )

find the process id: (assuming 8080 is the port)

```
lsof -i tcp:8080
```

kill it

```
kill <pid>
```

Answer (score 13):

### Use Airflow webserver's (gunicorn) signal handling

Airflow uses [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) as it's HTTP server, so you can send it standard POSIX-style signals. A signal commonly used by daemons to restart is `HUP`.

You'll need to locate the pid file for the airflow webserver daemon in order to get the right process id to send the signal to. This file could be in `$AIRFLOW_HOME` or also `/var/run`, which is where you'll find a lot of pids.

Assuming the pid file is in `/var/run`, you could run the command:

```
cat /var/run/airflow-webserver.pid | xargs kill -HUP
```

gunicorn uses a preforking model, so it has master and worker processes. The `HUP` signal is sent to the master process, which performs these actions:

> HUP: Reload the configuration, start the new worker processes with a new configuration and gracefully shutdown older workers. If the application is not preloaded (using the preload_app option), Gunicorn will also load the new version of it.

More information in the [gunicorn signal handling docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/signals.html).

This is mostly an expanded version of captaincapsaicin's answer, but using `HUP` (SIGHUP) instead of `KILL` (SIGKILL) to reload the process instead of actually killing it and restarting it.

Comment: Thanks, this works great for me while developing an Airflow plugin!  I'm using it with `entr` to auto-reload when I modify a file: `git ls-files | entr sh -c 'cat $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow-webserver.pid | xargs -t kill -HUP'`

Answer (score 5):

In my case i want to kill previous airflow process and start.
for that following command did the magic

```
killall -9 airflow
```

Comment: Yes! I had the incorrect launch of webserver without running service and this did exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

As the question was related to `webserver`, this is something that worked in my case:

`systemctl restart airflow-webserver`

Answer (score 2):

To restart Airflow you need to restart Airflow webserver and Airflow scheduler.

#### Check if Airflow servers are running:

```
ps -aux | grep airflow
```

if you see in list of running processes entries like:

```
ubuntu     49601  0.1  1.6 266668 135520 ?       S    12:19   0:00 [ready] gunicorn: worker [airflow-webserver]
```

This means that Airflow webserver is running.

If you see entries like this:

```
ubuntu     49653  0.6  2.3 308912 187596 ?       S    12:19   0:00 airflow scheduler -- DagFileProcessorManager
```

That means that Airflow scheduler is running.

#### Stop Airflow servers (webserver and scheduler):

```
pkill -f "airflow scheduler"
pkill -f "airflow webserver"
```

Now use again `ps -aux | grep airflow` to check if they are really shut down.

#### Start Airflow servers in background (daemon):

```
airflow webserver -D
airflow scheduler -D
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
airflow webserver -p 8080 -D
```

Answer (score 1):

Find `pid` with:

```
airflow webserver
```

will give: "The webserver is already running under PID **21250**."

Than kill web server process with:

`kill 21250`

Answer (score 0):

Create a init script and use the command "daemon" to run this as service.

```
daemon --user="${USER}" --pidfile="${PID_FILE}" airflow webserver -p 8090 >> "${LOG_FILE}" 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me. I had to delete the `$AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow-webserver.pid` file and then running `airflow webserver` worked.

Comment: Airflow prevent running in daemon mode when a pid file is still existing.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to create and enable the airflow webserver as a service. If you named the webserver as 'airflow-webserver', run the following command to restart the service:

systemctl restart airflow-webserver

You can use a ready-made AMI (namely, LightningFLow) from AWS Marketplace which provides Airflow services (webserver, scheduler, worker) which are enabled at startup.

Note: LightningFlow comes pre-integrated with all required libraries, Livy, custom operators, and local Spark cluster.

Link for AWS Marketplace: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Lightning-Analytics-Inc-LightningFlow-Integrated-o/B084BSD66V

Answer (score 0):

Just by killing processes!!

> Assuming the default airflow home directory is ~/airflow/

List the 3 parent processes running the airflow (PID):

```
cat ~/airflow/airflow-scheduler.pid
cat ~/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid
cat ~/airflow/airflow-webserver-monitor.pid
```

Get their PGID using:

```
ps -xjf
```

And finally run loop to kill all tree of each parent (PID):

```
for child in $(ps x -o "%P %p %r"| awk '{ if ( $1 == $your_first_PID || $3 == $your_first_PGID) { print $2 }}'); do kill $child; done
```