# Airflow - how to reload operators and plugins

Tags: airflow

I'm new with Airflow and I cannot understand how to reload an operator/plugin when I change its code.
I'm using the LocalExecutor and an external database (MySql).
I've tried to restart the webserver and the scheduler but I still get the same error when importing dags:

```
    File "/home/ec2-user/airflow/dags/extractor.py", line 2, in <module>
    from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_spark_plugin import EmrSparkOperator
ImportError: No module named emr_spark_plugin
```

Comment: Restarting the scheduler should work. Are you sure that you are calling the operator correctly?

Comment: My mistake. I should have called it as "from airflow.operators.emr_spark_plugin import EmrSparkOperator". Now restarting the scheduler and the webserver works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try restarting the web server and scheduler.

There isn't actually a good built-in way to do this, I recommend use systemd as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44022992/634627).

Answer (score 10):

I know that this is super old, but for those still looking for a good solution, new versions of Airflow now handle this automatically.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/configurations-ref.html#reload-on-plugin-change

You will need to set `reload_on_plugin_change = True` in your `airflow.cfg` file under the `[webserver]` section.

Comment: I'm running airflow locally with docker and this configuration doesn't seem to work for me. I need to restart webserver/scheduler for airflow to pick up plugins. any idea why?

Comment: It is the same for me "reload_on_plugin_change = True" does work properly. I also need to restart Airflow.