# Apache airflow 2.0 CORS issue

Tags: airflow, angular8

We are trying to hit apache airflow stable rest apis from our angular application. But we are getting CORS issue. We have set following in airflow.cfg file:

access_control_allow_headers = origin,content-type,accept

access_control_allow_methods = POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE

access_control_allow_origin = *

auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth

Still we are not able to see required headers in response.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get Airflow 2.2.4 running locally on macOS 11.6.4 following the [tutorial](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html) and using the `airflow standalone` command.

I kept getting CORS errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/vuex_storage_info' from origin
> 'http://0.0.0.0:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request
> client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private
> address space `local`.

Inspired by your question, I updated the following values in my `airflow.cfg` file:

```
access_control_allow_headers = origin,content-type,accept
access_control_allow_methods = POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
access_control_allow_origin = *
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default
```

(The only difference with your question being setting `auth_backend` to `default`).

Then I [restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43258101/1450420) the Airflow server and it worked.

Details on these settings are in the [configuration reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html).

Thanks for your help!